# How to bind to sub object first element in array?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to display first email in the array as the User email in a DataGrid Column.

This is how I get the data:

```
IEnumerable<User> dgUsers;
dgUsers = Context.Users.Where(u => u.Location == "UK")
                .Include(j => j.Emails).ToList();
```

And this is my XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding dgUsers}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,37,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding Surname}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Binding="{Binding Location}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Emails[0].Email}" Width="350"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastLogon" Binding="{Binding LastLogon}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

User Class definition:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLogon { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Mail> Emails { get; set; }
}
public class Mail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, the grid displays but Email column is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way is to create `UserViewModel` that define the first email as property. So your query will be something like.

```
IEnumerable<UserViewModel> dgUsers;
dgUsers = Context.Users.Where(u => u.Location == "UK")
                        .Include(j => j.Emails)
                        .Select(u => new UserViewModel() { /* some user properties */ Email = u.Emails.FirstOrDefault() }).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

The `ICollection` interface doesn't declare an indexer. So I suggest you use [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I can create ViewModel to do the same. But my question was related to the nested binding. I know it is possible, just don't know why it doesn't work on my example.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstood, Could you please update your post with `User` class definition

Comment: The`ICollection` interface doesn't declare an indexer. So I suggest you use [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) to solve your problem.

Comment: Wow it works, I new I was doing something wrong. Thank you!